# what would cause runcobol to fail for certain users?

Tags: centos, active-directory

I have RM/COBOL Runtime - Version 7.10.00 running on a CentOS 6.5 box (VM)

This CentOS allows SSH access to certain domain users by authenticating their group with the local domain controller.  These users get a home directory which is automatically created in /home/domainname/username, whereas normal local users reside in /home/username

The relevant Cobol files seem to reside in

`/usr/bin/runcobol` <- a file
`/usr/bin/rmcobolso` <- a directory, which seems to be empty according to `ls -a`

Anyway, here is my basic problem.  When a normal user runs the command

```
# runcobol
```

...which is just a basic check to see if the command works...
He/she receives the response:

```
RM/COBOL Runtime - Version 7.10.00 for Linux (Intel).
Configured for 50 users.
Copyright (c) 1985, 1986-2000 by Liant Software Corp.  All rights reserved.
Registration Number: 7H-1054-00367-0050

Usage:    RUNCOBOL name [options]
Options:  [A=arguments] [B=buffersize] [C=configfile] [D] [I] [K]
          [L=libname] [M] [S=switches] [T=sortsize] [V] [X=configmod]
```

When one of my domain users runs the command

```
# runcobol
```

He/she receives the response:

```
Segmentation fault
```

What could be causing this problem?

**Edit.1:**

`strace runcobol` from domain user. Last few lines included:

```
open("/usr/lib/libnss_winbind.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or direc
stat64("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
munmap(0xf76fa000, 48317)               = 0
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

These are just the last few lines.  The 20 lines preceeding this all seem to be looking for this `libnss_winbind.so.2` file, which DOES exist on my server in `/usr/lib64/libnss_winbind.so.2` (Yes, I'm running CentOS 6.5 64-bit).  From the first line of `strace runcobol`

```
[test.user.co@co1tu-sv-conta bin]$ strace runcobol
execve("/usr/bin/runcobol", ["runcobol"], [/* 26 vars */]) = 0
[ Process PID=14369 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
```

So, I'm guessing, but not sure, that I have a 64-bit version of `libnss_winbind.so.2` installed, but `runcobol` is looking for a 32-bit version.  So why does my normal user have no problem with `runcobol`?  Well, looking at the `strace` for the normal user, it doesn't seem to go looking for `libnss_winbind.so.2` at all.  I guess this makes sense, since `winbind` has something to do with samba and domain authentication, which the local user isn't doing.

At this point I'm kind of stuck again as I don't have a lot of experience debugging in linux.  I see three options from my limited guessing:

1. Find and install a 32-bit version of `libnss_winbind.so.2` in one of the locations that `runcobol` is looking for.  I have no idea which package to install for that on my 64-bit CentOS 6.5
2. Get `runcobol` to run without looking for `libnss_winbind.so.2`.  I'm not sure why it is looking to run with that since the user is already authenticated and in the CentOS system.  I am not using any domain resources after authentication, so it doesn't even seem like a necessary step.
3. `libnss_winbind.so.2` is a red herring and has nothing to do with the segmentation fault.

**Edit.2**

Results of `gdb runcobol` then `run`:

*From local user*

```
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/runcobol...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/runcobol

RM/COBOL Runtime - Version 7.10.00 for Linux (Intel).
Configured for 50 users.
Copyright (c) 1985, 1986-2000 by Liant Software Corp.  All rights reserved.
Registration Number: 7H-1054-00367-0050

Usage:    RUNCOBOL name [options]
Options:  [A=arguments] [B=buffersize] [C=configfile] [D] [I] [K]
          [L=libname] [M] [S=switches] [T=sortsize] [V] [X=configmod]

Program exited with code 0373.
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.4.i686
```

*From domain user*

```
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/runcobol...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/runcobol

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0805cc37 in OSINITIALIZE ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.4.i686
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in `runcobol`; it probably doesn't like something about the environment that it is run in when you execute it as a domain user. You could try to debug it with `gdb` and `strace`, maybe that'll give a hint what the actual problem is.

Comment: I was hoping it was something simple like 1. A configuration file for 'rubcobol', 2. A path setting for the domain user

Comment: Yeah, sorry, but without investigating the cause for the segfault you probably won't find a solution. Yes, the issue may be very simple (for example a missing environment variable or something), but without debugging the issue you probably won't find it.

Comment: OK I ran an strace from a normal user and from a domain user, and the domain user definitely seems to be following a different path.

Comment: I just posted new info in the original question under **Edit.1**

If you can help me out more that would be great.

Comment: Hmm, I can't really imagine that winbind has anything to do with it. At this point, the domain user has already been authenticated, and applications such as `runcobol` shouldn't have to be aware of the domain auth in the background. Maybe a `gdb` backtrace is more helpful?

Comment: I will try `gdb` now, but somehow `runcobol` is aware it is a domain user.  I did `strace runcobol -o runcobol.txt` with my local user, and then searched the output for `winbind` and `runcobol` doesn't go looking for `winbind` at all...

Comment: Added **Edit.2** with the results of `gdb`

Comment: I think you need to do a `bt` in `gdb`... I hope somebody else can chime in here because I'm unfortunately not very experienced with `gdb`.

Comment: When I send `bt` I just get this `#0  0x0805cc37 in OSINITIALIZE ()` which doesn't seem to be new info...

Comment: Any chance I could resurrect this thread?  Anyone have any ideas?